# What's the difference between @After and @Finally annotations for Play controllers

Tags: java, annotations, controller, playframework

The documentation isn't very clear on this.  Can someone illuminate the differences between these two?

`@After` - Methods annotated with the @After annotation are executed after each action call for this Controller.

`@Finally` - Methods annotated with the @Finally annotation are executed after each action result is applied from for this Controller.

Would it hurt performance to use @Finally when @After would work?

Comment: Your behavior may differ...@Finally methods get called later than @After methods do, and this may affect how the methods behave.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you write a small test harness, you will see how this works, but the crux of it is this

- @Before is called before you action is executed
- @After is called after your controller has completed its execution, but before the output is rendered to the browser
- @Finally is called when the results have been posted to the browser.

So in most cases, @After and @Finally will work for you in the same way, but do have a slight difference, depending on your particular use-case. It shouldn't make any difference to performance however.

The test harness that I wrote to prove this, is as follows

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    @Before
    static void log0() {Logger.info("before: "+ response.out.size());}
    @After
    static void log1() {Logger.info("After: "+ response.out.size());}
    @Finally
    static void log2() {Logger.info("finally: "+ response.out.size());}

    public static void index() {
        Logger.info("in index action");
        render();
    }
}
```

The output I get is as follows

```
20:51:37,741 INFO  ~ before: 0
20:51:37,742 INFO  ~ in index action
20:51:38,083 INFO  ~ After: 0
20:51:38,106 INFO  ~ finally: 706
```

Which clearly shows the order of processing, and the data being outputted to the the HTTP Response object.